# javascript SOAP xmlhttprequest issue mobile

Tags: soap, mobile, xmlhttprequest, onreadystatechange

All right, so previously I asked...
SOAP Prototype AJAX SOAPAction Header Question (can't hyperlink it unfortunately, not enough rep for "2" links... see below)

Which never worked out.  I think it has something to do with Prototype, it will return a 0 as onSuccess.  I can't figure out the Content-type utf-8 formatting.  Now if I go back to straight javascript and use xmlhttprequest

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

```
    function getUVIndex() {
        // In Firefox, we must ask the user to grant the privileges we need to run.
        // We need special privileges because we're talking to a web server other
        // than the one that served the document that contains this script. UniversalXPConnect
        // allows us to make an XMLHttpRequest to the server, and
        // UniversalBrowserRead allows us to look at its response.
        // In IE, the user must instead enable "Access data sources across domains"
        // in the Tools->Internet Options->Security dialog.
        if (typeof netscape != "undefined") {
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.
                    enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect UniversalBrowserRead");
        }
        // Create an XMLHttpRequest to issue the SOAP request. This is a utility
        // function defined in the last chapter.
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // We're going to be POSTing to this URL and want a synchronous response
        request.open("POST", "http://iaspub.epa.gov/uvindexalert/services/UVIndexAlertPort?wsdl", false);

        request.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (request.readyState==4) {
                    var index = request.responseXML.getElementByTagName('index')[0].firstChild.data;
                    alert(request.responseText);
                }
            }
        // Set some headers: the body of this POST request is XML
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        // This header is a required part of the SOAP protocol
        request.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", '""');
        // Now send an XML-formatted SOAP request to the server
        request.send(               
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
            '<soap:Envelope' +
            ' xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
            ' xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"' +
            ' xmlns:tns="urn:uvindexalert" xmlns:types="urn:uvindexalert/encodedTypes"' +
            ' xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
            ' xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' +
            '  <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +
            '    <tns:getUVIndexAlertByZipCode>' +
            '       <in0 xsi:type="xsd:string">12306</in0>' +
            '   </tns:getUVIndexAlertByZipCode>' +
            '  </soap:Body>' +
            '</soap:Envelope>'

            );
        // If we got an HTTP error, throw an exception
        if (request.status != 200) throw request.statusText;

        //return request.responseXML.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[5].textContent;
    }

    getUVIndex();
</script>
```

This never calls the onreadystatechange.  If you uncomment the 
return request.responseXML.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[5].textContent;

It will retrieve the value needed and if you are in Firebug you will see the readyState == 4 and status == 200 (not that I check for that).  I usually never need to be spoon fed but I just don't understand why I am not getting the values back I need from the listener, or why it is never called.  Also, not that this should matter really but I am approving the request on Firefox to be cross-domain, it is really for mobile so the call will not need to be have a confirmation of cross-domain, it will do that automatically.

I hope someone can look at this and see what I overlooked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onreadystatechange will only be called for asynchronous requests to the server, your code is sending a synchronous request.

Set the third parameter on the open call to true (or remove the third parameter as default is true).

```
request.open("POST", "http://iaspub.epa.gov/uvindexalert/services/UVIndexAlertPort?wsdl", true);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536648(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Man!  Thank you so much.  Racking my brain!  I can now move on with my life!